# IBM CDC i Series DR Planning (Situation: Target Ahead AS400 Source)

Tags: websphere, ibm-midrange, cdc

I am planning a new environment with IBM CDC between AS400 and Linux (DB2).

[image]

As the diagram is showing the situation, Journal A04 was the producton latest journal position.  Unfortunately, it is possible for the DR not synchonized up to the point A04 and say A02.

Then, the target may be synchonized up to A03.  How do I recover the CDC replication (w/o full initial load)?  Can I get the journal positon of A02 to modify the target database?

It is possible to have a large table with 100G.  The downtime for reinitialization is really a concern.  Is there any clue for solving this possible situation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above diagram, would you please confirm on if A03 & A04 will be synched to DR source by HA solution?
If Yes, then extract the last applied position from the production target and set that to the source DR subscription's position to resume replication to production target.

Thanks.

Comment: If I have a HA solution, I am not sure the journal information (also sequence number) being the same for the Production and DR AS400.  Which HA solution is recommended? e.g. MIMIX